# Why I Can't Run React Native Project (Transform Error)

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I can't run this project.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {  View,  Text, ImageBackground, Dimensions} from 'react-native';

const {width, height} = Dimensions.get('window');

class Form extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <ImageBackground source={require('../img/bg.jpg')} style={{width, height, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center'}}>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text style={{paddingLeft:10, color:'white'}}>Başlangıç Konumu</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={styles.section}>
          <Text style={{paddingLeft:10, color:'white'}}>Varış Konumu</Text>
        </View>
        <View style={{backgroundColor: 'orange',
        width: width*0.95, marginTop: 40, flexDirection: 'row',
        justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', height: height*0.075}}>
          <Text style={{color:'white', fontSize:20}}>KM Hesapla</Text>
        </View>
        </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}

export default Form;
```

Response error 500 in line 25, column 21. I tried delete this page but not working. Why i can't run this project ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, are you really talking about a ReactJS application in the web browser rather than ReactNative on a Mobile Device? This error often deals with Babel.

Also, I wouldn't name your class Form.  Be more specific.  What type of form?

Delete your node_modules folder.

Then execute these on your command line.

npm cache clean

npm i

Comment: I'm new at react native. Cache clean worked. Thanks.

Comment: I can't do this because reputation record,  sorry :)